# Including vars into an Ansible playbook

Tags: postgresql, yaml, web-deployment, ansible

I wanted to give deploying django projects with ansible a shot but I'm stuck on what seems to be a pretty basic issue.

I've created a basic playbook to deploy my Postgres server.

```
---
- hosts: default
  remote_user: myusername
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: postgres
  vars:
    - include: vars/databases.yml

  tasks:

     - name: Ensure Postgres server is running
       service: name=postgresql state=started enabled=yes

    - name: Create postgres database
      postgresql_db:
        name: '{{ db_name }}'
        state: present
        encoding: 'UTF-8'
```

I run the playbook and I get this error

```
fatal: [default]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "'db_name' is undefined"}
```

In order to keep all of my passwords and such out of version control I've created a directory vars. It's located in my project structure like this with all my ansible yaml files in deploy and all my vars files in the vars subdirectory.

```
..
├── deploy
│   └── vars
..
├── myproject
├── manage.py
└── utils


# var/databases.yml
db_name: <database name>
```

What's going on here?

**Update:** Added contents of var/databases.yml as requested.

Comment: Where is your playbook located? Under `myproject`?

Comment: The playbook is located in the deploy directory.

Answer (score 0):

The variable db_name must be assigned a value before trying to create a database. the error clearly stating that <"'db_name' is undefined">, the variable db_name is undefined/unassigned.

See below sample code for an example

```
vars:
  dbname: myapp
  dbuser: django
  dbpassword: mysupersecretpassword

tasks:
- name: ensure database is created
  postgresql_db: name={{dbname}}
```

Comment: But the question states that he includes the vars from an external file, how does this help?

Comment: Exactly...in this case I'd just be leaking the name of directory but in the future I'd like to use var files to allow me to reuse these playbooks as well as to protect sensitive info under version control.

Comment: @guptam Can you share the content of your external variable file content

Comment: I've added the contents of the vars/databases.yml file as requested...hopefully not too late!

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the the `vars` with `vars_files` like this:

```
vars_files:
    - vars/databases.yml
```

Comment: I've tried that but there is no difference. Same errors.